# Visual Studio 2017 doesn't compile small changes to code when building for release

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, compilation

This happens sometimes when I make small changes to the source code, like removing a line of code or changing some value.

**case A**

1. change `player.y = 100;` to `player.y = 250;`
2. compile code with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>
3. player still appear at `y: 100`
4. change `player.symbol = "O";` to `player.symbol = "P";`
5. compile code with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>
6. player now appear at the correct location `y: 250`

**So far I've tried**

- Clean Solution - this works, but I'd rather not have to rely on this whenever I make a change
- `Build` is checked for the project under `Build > Configuration Manager...`
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> still compiles the wrong code.
- running VS as administrator - still compiles the wrong code.
- I've looked at the executable's creation date. It doesn't update when I compile.
- deleting the executable before compiling re-creates the same executable without the changes.
- I had the same issue on another visual studio installation on the same computer

The project is located on a local hard drive.

**edit:** 
I found this [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/163417/c-floating-point-constants-not-being-detected-as-c.html). The problem seem to be very similar, although when testing right now it extends to more than just editing float numbers. I'm using Visual Studio Community Version 15.7.1, but had this problem prior to patching as well.

This doesn't seem to occur (so far) while building for debug.

Comment: What's the error that's being reported by the compiler? Also: are you editing the code through the IDE, or with an external text editor?

Comment: I'm programming in the visual studio IDE. There is no error message, it compiles and run the executable (without the changes).

Comment: @Angew how do I know for sure? If I delete the executable it re-creates it with the same unchanged code.

Comment: Are you sure ctrl+f5 is a compile command under your key map? With my selection ctrl+f5 is run without debugging, to compile is "f7", to compile only the current file (only works if a source file is focused and not a header) it is "ctrl+f7", rebuild solution is "ctrl+alt+f7". Look on the build menu and make sure of your shortcut keys.

Answer (score 3):

It may seem like a pain, but after making any significant changes it is usually a good idea to clean the solution and rebuild the project. You may think that recompiling a single translation unit will work and in some cases that may be true, but if other object files rely on the translation unit you just updated they need to be recompiled as well otherwise visual studio will use the older object files that have previously been built.

As for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> whether you are in `debug` or `release` mode just tells Visual Studio that you want to run without debugging as it has nothing to do with the compilation and building of the project or solution. Are you sure you are not confusing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> as user `SoronelHateir` has mentioned in the commmets? After you make any changes to source code it is good to first recompile that individual file to make sure there are no compilation errors. Then it is good to rebuild that current project within the solution.

On the other hand if your solution has multiple projects for example: one project is a library that is statically linked and the other project is your main executable project and the changes you made are in your library and depending on how the main project depends on the library project you will probably have to more than likely at the least rebuild the library project and in some cases you may even have to rebuild the main startup project. Most of the times just rebuilding the statically linked library should suffice; it is rare that the main program that is linking the library would have to be rebuilt to see the new changes, but there are some rare cases that both will have to be rebuilt.

I'll say it again; yes it may seem like a pain to have to do a clean solution and complete rebuild, but after a while this is the safest path to travel to ensure that all of the object files are up to date. What you are seeing in your own solution is a side effect of running the program with updated code but the output matches that of the older object files. This is a result of the IDE using the older or stale object files that already exist since you did not rebuild the solution. Cleaning the solution clears out all of the old object files as well as any intermediate files that are used to compile the source code into translation units to make the appropriate object files.

There are settings within the IDE that others have mentioned above such as user: `Bo Persson` has stated from their answer that you can change the behavior of how Visual Studio will recompile, rebuild a project or solution.

Answer (score -1):

In visual studio, after making changes, I always click(in the menu bar):

**Build** -- **Rebuild Solution**

Note that this is different from "<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>" and "<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd>"
And it will always pick up all the changes and recompile your program

Comment: For large projects, this is terrible advice, as it will rebuild *everything*. It's basically equivalent to `make clean; make all`. If the full solution's build time is counted in hours, and you've changed one small `.dll`, rebuild all is *not* what you want.

Answer (score -1):

I tried everything mentioned in the current solutions and it didn't work for me. However after a lot of frustration I realized I was running my debugger. Try going to the **Debug** tab then press **Stop Debugging**. Finally make sure to select **Release** from this dropdown box(Mine was on **Debug**). [image: referenced dropdown]